# Getting the selected radio button value

Tags: jquery, radio-button

```
$("#poll1p").append("<input type='radio' name='radio1' id='r1' /><label for='radio1'>"+x[0]+"</label><br>");
$("#poll1p").append("<input type='radio' name='radio1' id='r2' /><label for='radio1'>"+x[1]+"</label><br>");
```

the values `x[0]` and `x[1]` are array values. I am not able to get the selected radio button value by using

```
$("input:radio[name='radio1']:checked").val();
```

If i use the above,i just get "ON" as a return value... I need the value from

Comment: Could we see your html and where you are trying to get the radio button's value and why?  There isn't enough information here to be helpful.

Comment: html is a very big file ... I cant add it completely ... What i am doing is , i get the labels for radio buttons from the database based on some criteria and i display it as a form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify a `value="..."` attribute for your radio buttons if you want some value besides "on" returned.

Use the following, and you should get back `1` or `2` from `.val()`:

```
<input type='radio' name='radio1' id='r1' value="1" />
<input type='radio' name='radio1' id='r2' value="2" />
```

Not related, but you also need to use `for="r1"` and `for="r2"` for your lables - ie, use an element's `id` as the value of the `for` attribute of its label.

Comment: can i put a javascript variable as the value for "value" attribute ... ??

Comment: @hari No, but you can can use JS to dynamically assign values to each radio button based on ID when the document loads.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a value='' attribute on the radio buttons you are appending.